Android studio emulator not opening with error
I'm working on a laptop - Lenovo Thinkbook 14 with Intel i7-1065G7 CPU. Windows 11 home.
I have installed the latest version of Android studio.
Upon creating a new file, I try to open the emulator and get the following error:
enter image description here
Does anyone have another idea or have had this problem and managed to solve it?
Thanks!
I have tried: reinstalling Android simulator
reinstalling windows from 0
updating my graphic drivers

Try not to provide external links that may not be available in the future. The image also does not encapsulate the error description clearly. Scroll down the error description and paste the entire error message. Hope this is helpful!
